# mysql query order by case when and field

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, field, case

does anybody have an idea how to speed up this query.

i am looking for keywords "bar" and "cafe" in several fields on just 1 table as seen below, then i want to order it by their most fitting hit so i do all the field and case when- possibilities, of course this is slowing it down a lot, tho what can i do to speed it up?

1. first i order by the exact hit with FIELD which in this case makes no sense because keyword is bar and cafe but when i look up for "company name" then i want this company to be #1
2. then i try to order by similar name / name part if the exact one doesnt hit due field.
3. after that i order by "amount" which can be 8,30€ to 500€ whatever and after that there are coming loads with 0€ which are the free entry's
4. and then i again with all the free entry's i try to order them by "case when" with several wildcards

the problem is actually the order by, the query itself takes just about 0,02 seconds without any order while with the order by it takes about 5-7 seconds.
tho i might be wrong and i can speed this up already within the query...?

the fields have of course indexes.

any help would be highly appreciated :)

```
 select * FROM companytable where 
 companytable.aktiv='1'
 and platform='1'
 and (lcase(companytable.company_name) like '%bar%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_name_modrewrite) like '%bar%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_www) like '%bar%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_nachname) like '%bar%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_home_text) like '%bar%'
 or lcase(companytable.keywords) like '%bar%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_name) like '%cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_name_modrewrite) like '%cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_www) like '%cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_nachname) like '%cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_home_text) like '%cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.keywords) like '%cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_name) like '%bar cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_name_modrewrite) like '%bar_cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_www) like '%bar cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_nachname) like '%bar cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.company_home_text) like '%bar cafe%'
 or lcase(companytable.keywords) like '%bar cafe%')
order by 
 FIELD(lcase(companytable.company_name),'bar cafe') desc,
 FIELD(lcase(companytable.company_name),'cafe bar') desc,
case when lcase(companytable.company_name) LIKE "%cafe bar%" then 1 END desc,
case when lcase(companytable.company_name) LIKE "%bar cafe%" then 1 END desc,
cast(companytable.amount as unsigned) desc,
case when lcase(companytable.company_name) LIKE "bar cafe%" then 1 END desc,
case when lcase(companytable.company_name) LIKE "%bar cafe%" then 1 END desc,
case when lcase(companytable.company_name) LIKE "%bar cafe" then 1 END desc,
case when lcase(companytable.company_name) LIKE "cafe bar%" then 1 END desc,
case when lcase(companytable.company_name) LIKE "%cafe bar%" then 1 END desc,
case when lcase(companytable.company_name) LIKE "%cafe bar" then 1 END desc,
FIELD(lcase(companytable.company_name),'bar cafe') desc,
companytable.company_name
```

Comment: `FIELD(lcase(companytable.company_name),'bar cafe')` is probably not what you want. When you use `FIELD`, each string you're testing for has to be a separate argument, not space-separated. So it should be `FIELD(lcase(companytable.company_name),'bar', 'cafe')`

Comment: well this is actually what i want because it shall not separate these two words for exact hit, tho this helps me already beacause i made two fields and can combine it in one. one step further... :) thank you

Comment: It makes little sense to use `FIELD` with just 2 arguments. `FIELD(x, y)` is the same as `x = y`.